# How to import or create notebook in synapse using CLI

Tags: azure-synapse

How to create notebooks in synapse using GitHub via CLI commands.

I am unable to create the notebooks.

Please provide step by step instructions

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example:

```
az synapse notebook export --workspace-name syn-ggtest1 --name mynotebook --output-folder ./
az synapse notebook import --workspace-name syn-ggtest1 --name mynotebook --file @./mynotebook.ipynb
```

A few things to be aware of:

1. The notebook will only be visible in synapse studio if you're in
   "live mode". If your workspace is connected to a git repo, you need
   to import a notebook by adding the json file to the "notebook"
   folder in your repo.
2. You have to use the .ipynb format (this is the
   format you get when you do an export via cli) to do the
   import/create, not the .json (this is the format you get when you
   commit to git)
3. The notebook will get created at the root level in
   Synapse studio (the "folder" property in the .ipynb is ignored)

Comment: This post contains more information then all of the official documents.

Comment: Is it possible to trigger a "publish" on a Workspace using GIT if I have pushed my changes to the branch, so that it populates the publish branch for me?

Comment: This works if you have the workspace with the actual notebooks. In my case, I have the data from the repo and I'm trying to rebuild the workspace. Not sure why Microsoft would not allow a json file as the ones checked in by Synapse.

Answer (score -2):

> How to import or create notebook in synapse using CLI?

You can use Azure CLI commands to create and import notebooks.

[image]

**Reference:** [az synapse notebook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/synapse/notebook?view=azure-cli-latest)

Comment: Thank you for the answers, but I am looking for step by step instructions to create notebooks