# az synapse notebook import from powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-synapse, azure-cli

I'm trying to upload synapse notebook via cmd using `azure cli`.
I found nice and neat doc here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/synapse/notebook?view=azure-cli-latest#az-synapse-notebook-import  but unfortunately I'm getting always error, I'm struggling with --file parameter.

The doc claims:

`--file`
Properties may be supplied from a JSON file using the @{path} syntax or a JSON string.

> Import a notebook. Pay attention to add "@" at the front of the file path as the best practice for complex arguments like JSON string.

Here my powershell code:

```
az login --service-principal --username ** --password ** --tenant **
az account set --subscription ***

$filePath = @{
    path = "test.ipynb"
}

az synapse notebook import --workspace-name synworkspace --name test --file $filePath --folder-path 'root/'
```

> error:
> Failed to parse string as JSON:
> System.Collections.Hashtable
> Error detail: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

I've tried different solutions but always getting errors. I've tried passing json as string, only a string containing path etc but none works.

Someone can show me a solution that works correctly?

Any advice will be appreciated

### Edit

to answer RithwikBojja, this is my output:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `$filePath = @{path = "test.ipynb"} | ConvertTo-Json`?

Comment: yep, this was the error: Failed to parse string as JSON:
{
Error detail: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Comment: AFAIK JSON5 doesn't require quotes around property names but regular JSON does, so maybe try: `$filePath = @{"path" = "test.ipynb"} | ConvertTo-Json`?

Comment: nope :( same error

Comment: I googled and found a sample here. Does this work? If so we can mark as a duplicate. (and also upvote the answer since it's more helpful than the official doco) https://stackoverflow.com/a/68561795/1690193

Comment: for me is not working

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:

Below is the command which worked for me and I have followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/synapse/notebook?view=azure-cli-latest#az-synapse-notebook-import):

```
az synapse notebook import --workspace-name rithwik6 --name RithwikTestNoteBook2 --file  "@C:\Users\Downloads\Nb1.ipynb" --folder-path 'root/'
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

Here you should give **--file** as **"@Nb1.ipynb"**.

Try to follow above way to get the file imported as I have got.

**`In Portal after Imported:`**

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, but is still not working for me. I've uploaded my output

Comment: It worked for me as i got output and pasted the screenshots, also try this **`@"C:\Users\me\Downloads\xxx.ipynb"**

Comment: Or Use **'@C:\Users\me\Downloads\2021\xxx.ipynb'** and Here In first used **`** and in 2nd used **'**. Also check [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70659370).

Comment: I can't understand why but I'm always getting same error. Maybe something due to waring I get? ***The provided JSON string may have been parsed by the shell. See https://docs.microsoft.com/cli/azure/use-cli-effectively#use-quotation-marks-in-arguments
PowerShell requires additional quoting rules. See https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/blob/dev/doc/quoting-issues-with-powershell.md***